# How to use the web api url across the mvc application

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

here is my piece of sample code

```
 function AuthenticateLogin() {
            $.getJSON('http://localhost:52293/api/APILogin/', function (data) {
                if (data != null) {

                }
            }
            );
        }
```

The hosting url is below, which will be used across the mvc application, might be the controller/action will be varied across the application.

> `http://localhost:52293`

for example, here i have hard coded the above url in all places, If I'm moving the application to other machine,then it is not good to change the url again in each and every places. so, is there any way to handle this ?

Comment: checkout out UrlHelper.HttpRouteUrl(String, Object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your API action a static name:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/APILogin")]
public class APILoginApiController {
    [Route("", Name = "Login")]
    public ActionResult Login(string userName) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then in your Razor JavaScript, you can utilize the UrlHelper by calling [Url.HttpRouteUrl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj128146(v=vs.118).aspx) to dynamically build your URL for you.

```
$.getJSON('@Url.HttpRouteUrl("Login", new {})', function (data) {
    // ...
});
```

The advantage of this approach is that if you change anything about how the route is formulated, it's in the `[Route]` attribute on the action. Matching the name like that will use the routing engine to always create the correct path. Otherwise, you're still stuck with (partial) hard-coded paths throughout your JavaScript.

If your route requires any variables, then that is provided within the empty anonymous object as the second parameter for `HttpRouteUrl()`.

Comment: it says ,The route template cannot start with a '/' or > '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have that part in front of me to check. Just have it start with "api". I'll fix the answer.

Comment: @krillgar I fixed it.

Comment: @King_Fisher yes that is an anonymous type used to pass parameters relevant to the url generation.

Comment: Correct. If you have a  parameter named "id", you would do `new { id = widget.Id }`, or what have you. Since you didn't have it as a part of the question, I didn't include an example as it would be broader.

Comment: I have added another Web api controller, I couldnot able to make a call to new web api controller.  @krillgar

Answer (score 2):

You should not hardcode the full absolute url like that. You may consider using the relative url. To generate relative url, you may consider using the Url helper methods

If your code is inside an external js file, you should consider using the helper method to generate the relative url in your razor view(s) and store it in a js variable which you can use in your external js files.

In your razor view

```
<script>
    var myApp = myApp || {};
    myApp.siteBaseUrl = "@Url.Content("~")";  // Get the app root 
</script>
```

Now in your external js files

```
$.getJSON(myApp.siteBaseUrl+'api/APILogin/', function (data) {
     // do something
});
```

You can also use `Url.RouteUrl` helper method to generate the urls to the api endpoints. For example

```
var myApp = myApp || {};    
myApp.productsApiUrl = "@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", 
                                        new { httproute = true, controller = "Products"})";
```

Now somewhere else in the js codde, you can use it like

```
$.getJSON(myApp.productsApiUrl , function (data) {
     // do something with products data
});
```

This approach allows you to pass route values when you make the call and the helper method will build the url for you (based on the route definition)

```
myApp.productsDetailsUrl = "@Url.RouteUrl("DefaultApi", 
                              new { httproute = true, controller = "Products", id= 210 })";
```